# Callback list functions in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have 2 lists: `inl` and `outl`

In Plotly Dash, I want to create a callback function that will move a item in the list between the 2 lists.

So for example I want to be able to move 'a' from `inl` to `outl`, and then back again.

This is my code so far. Can anyone see the issue?

```
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

inl=['a','b','c']
outl=['x','y','z']

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(className="trend",children=[html.Ul(id='list1', children=[html.Li(i) for i in inl])],)
    ,html.Div(className="trend2",children=[html.Ul(id='list2', children=[html.Li(i) for i in outl])],)
]
)

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='list2', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='list1', component_property='value') 

def insertvar(input):
    inl.append(input)
                

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode='external')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct version

```
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table

inl = ['a', 'b', 'c']
outl = ['x', 'y', 'z']

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(className="trend", children=[html.Ul(id='list1', children=[html.Li(i) for i in inl])], )
    , html.Div(className="trend2", children=[html.Ul(id='list2', children=[html.Li(i) for i in outl])], )
]
)


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='list2', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='list1', component_property='value')
)
def insertvar(input):
    inl.append(input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```